# Overlay a Text on Image with responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I am spending my time hard to place a Text on an image with mobile response.  Actually I am building a HTML5 jQuery Mobile cordova mobile app.

**This is the sample screen in smaller device.**

[image]

**This is the sample screen in big device.**

[image]
I want to place the text `Some Text` over the image on the bottom side aligned center with responsive.

This is the code on jQuery Mobile produces the image and text.

```
<div class="ui-block-a">
  <div class="ui-bar" style="padding:5px">
    <img style="height: 100%;width:100%" src='img/book150.png'/>
     <p id="text">Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried with the below CSS style but this only work if I have the image size constant in one size.

```
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Code?  Have you tried to do it yourself?  If so what did you try and the results?

Comment: put the css you applied for `ui-block-a` and `ui-bar` to understand the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give parent a `position:relative` in order to make it work.

To horizontally center a block element positioned `absolute`ly  you need to apply this:

```
position:absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned
>   element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor(non
>   static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container
>   is used.

#### Snippet

```css
.ui-block-a {
  position: relative;
  max-width:150px; /*you need to set a max-width/width */
}
.ui-bar {
  padding: 5px
}
#text {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
   /*demo*/
  bottom: 5px;
  background: red;
  max-width:100px;
  text-align:center

}
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-block-a">
  <div class="ui-bar">
    <img src='//lorempixel.com/150/150' />
    <p id="text">Some Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I understand the `position:relative`.  Instead of hard code `left:7%` is there a way that can be aligned center inside the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `#text` with `p`.  So from:

```
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 350px;
}
```

To:

```
p {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 350px;
}
```

Comment: this won't do anything.